# After changing name & domain of orderer & peers user is not getting enrolled in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i am new to hyperledger & trying to modify existing balance transfer example in fabric sample. Here change i am doing is changing the name & domain of orderer & peers in **cryptogen.yaml** file. Also made changes accordingly in configtx.yaml & docker-compose.yaml files. Here is the change in  cryptogen.yaml file :

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: say.com

    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer

PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Customer1
    Domain: customer1.say.com
    CA:
       Hostname: ca

    Template:
      Count: 2
      SANS:
        - "localhost"

    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: Customer2
    Domain: customer2.say.com
    CA:
       Hostname: ca

    Template:
      Count: 2
      SANS:
        - "localhost"
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Here is configtx.yaml file :

```
Profiles:
    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Customer1
                    - *Customer2
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Customer1
                - *Customer2

Organizations:
    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererMSP
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/say.com/msp

    - &Customer1
        Name: Customer1MSP
        ID: Customer1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/customer1.say.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.customer1.say.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Customer2
        Name: Customer2MSP
        ID: Customer2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/customer2.say.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.customer2.say.com
              Port: 7051

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo
    Addresses:
        - orderer.say.com:7050
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092
    Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
```

I am able to generate crypto materials using cryptogen tool & container is getting up. Using **docker ps** i can see all the containers. At the time of enrolling user getting following error :

> [DEBUG] Helper - [FileKeyValueStore.js]: FileKeyValueStore.js -
>   constructor  [ERROR] Helper - Failed to get registered user: Jim,
>   error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStateStore' of undefined
>       at hfc.newDefaultKeyValueStore.then (/home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/app/helper.js:208:9)

Please let me know what is the reason i am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to **app/helper.js** file (line number 38),
which is `if (key.indexOf('org') === 0) {`
the org name must begin with '**org**' keyword.

for example, org name can be **orgDemo** but ***can not be*** **Demo**

Comment: its not docker issue, since i can see container is getting up.

Comment: let me check if i can bring it up with same configs

Comment: did you login with 'Jim' first? in response you will get an accesstoken, you have to store it.

Comment: since user is not getting enrolled, so we are not able to login. And we got error mentioned above. I am running runApp.sh script in balance transfer which stops then start container.

Comment: i am able to regenerate the issue.. trying to debug it

Comment: Thanks a lot Adesh...i am able to enroll the user after changing above piece of code, here is the change : if (key.indexOf('Customer1') === 0 || key.indexOf('Customer2') === 0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know balance transfer, but most of the examples mount local directories for the docker containers in the docker configs to point to the crypto on the local file system. You'll need to either modify those to point to your new crypto paths or copy your new crypto into the existing dirs.

Additionally, the genesis block and channel creation must be created with the same organizations and crypto. I don't know if balance transfer will recreate the genesis block and channel to match or not. There's also often a couple peer and domain names specified in the docker definitions that need to match those in the configtx.yaml.

Users must be registered with the CA before they can enroll. Even if all the above is correct you may still need to register Jim manually if the scripts don't do that for you.

Either Jim is not registered, or you're not pointing to the correct CA container names or crypto paths, or the genesis block is still using the original Org names and crypto paths, etc. You can use 
configtxgen  -inspectBlock genesisblockfilename and 
configtxgen -inspectChannelCreateTx channelfilename to see what Orgs are included.

Comment: docker compose is also configured according to the change in configtx.yaml & cryptogen.yaml file. If same example we are running with Org1 & Org2 it is running properly & able to enroll the user. I am not able to figure out the issue behind it.